# BLToolkit update with non IQueryable

Tags: list, bltoolkit

So far I was using something like this if I wanted to update table.

```
var myData = from t1 in db.Table1
where ...
select new { do some math here };
```

and then I would call

```
myData.Update( db.Table2, x => new Table2
{
    update columns here
}
```

That works great, but now I need to convert the **myData** query into List() so I can use that same data later in another update call.
The problem with IQueryable is that when I call the Update for the second time later in code with this "myData", it includes data which were affected between the two updates, and I want the data as they were before the first update was called.

So I need this

```
var myData = (from t1 in db.Table1
where ...
select new { do some math here }).ToList();
```

to update table using the same call as before.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myData =
    from t1 in db.Table1
    where ...
    select new { do some math here };

var myDataList = myData.ToList();

myData.Update( db.Table2, x => new Table2
{
   update columns here
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not exactly. I need this

myDataList.Update( db.Table2, x => new Table2
{
   update columns here
}

but it's not possible because myDataList is now object and not query